# Create Static Libraries from Github repositories in Windows

Tags: c++, eclipse

I want to understand what is the process to follow to create a static library (.a) from the files downloaded from a Github repository. I've noticed that usually come "Makefile" "Config" "Build" files but I do not know how to run them and at what point the library is created. I'm using Windows 10 and I do not know if it's any good but download the Ubuntu application that is in Microsoft Store (I did this because I thought they were Linux commands).

I need to create static libraries because apparently they are the only ones that IngeDev (IDE based on Eclipse) supports and allows to use.

Comment: No easy answer for you, I'm afraid. If the library developers did not provide instructions for building on your tool chain, you'll probably have to come up with them yourself. If your tools are GCC-based and came with a Linux-like build environment (cygwin, msys) you can probably use the instructions given with minimal modification. If not... I feel your pain.

Comment: @user4581301 Maybe if I saw an example of one I could replicate it in others, the problem is that there is no info or tutorial or I have not found it

Comment: If IngeDev is backed by the GCC tool chain, you may find the offerings from https://www.msys2.org/ allow you to closely follow the Linux build instructions, but like I said, if you aren't given build instructions to produce a static library building your own set could be a dramatic chore. Now way to tell without knowing which library you're fighting with. Recommend adding one of the repositories to your question. I might recognize it, but more likely someone else will. Perhaps even one of the writers. Lot of interesting folks hanging around here.

Comment: @user4581301 All this started because IngeDev does not come with "libcurl" so I thought to create the static library from the source code "src" but it was not as easy as I thought, so I wanted to try to build it from the "makefile" (all apparently do it so) but I got more questions than answers, this is the link of libcurl in git https://github.com/curl/curl

Comment: I have successfully built cURL under windows 10 with GCC 4.8 supplied by Mingw-64 and msys. My notes unfortunately are sparse: /*
 The making of curl:

 First make openssl
 ./configure mingw64
 make depends
 make

 then hack lib/Makefile.m32 to point at openssl and remove references to
 alternative locations for ssl
 Enter lib directory and
 make -n -f Makefile.m32 CFG=-ssl
*/ This may (probably) have been after I ran ./configure. Your tool chain is likely not mingw64, so some research is required.